# IntroJs step is partially off screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, intro.js

I am using introJS in an app and one of the steps is appearing partially off-screen. I have tried setting position to auto, left, right, etc, but this item always appears this way (the other "steps' appear within the window). Does anyone have any ideas about how I can resolve this? [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oauxa.png)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still have the same issue. I solved this by adding right: 0; into custom tooltip class.